# Getting value from broadcasted map is taking lot of time in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have three nodes Spark cluster . I am preparing one map and broadcasting map so that it is available at every node. But it is taking a lot of time to fetch data from broadcasted map.
Broadcasted Map has 1.4 million records.

I am broadcasting map in this way:

```
 val  SDF3_boradcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(SDF3.collectAsList.toMap)
```

And getting value through it in this way:

```
val sd_studentTemp = SDF3_boradcast.value.get(key).get
```

Why is it taking lot of time and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What could be the size of those 14L records in Mb/Gb, and what is the executor memory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I suspect this is the case because broadcast variables are usually quite small, and should fit in Executor memory. 
Map-side joins (where the map is broadcasted) are generally used when the map is quite small. 
Quote from [this blog about map-side joins](https://www.edureka.co/blog/map-side-join-vs-join/)

> **Disadvantages of Map-side join:**
>       Map side join is adequate only when one of the tables on which you perform map-side join operation is small enough to fit into the memory.  Hence it is not suitable to perform map-side join on the tables which are huge data in both of them.

If your map is as large as you indicate, consider making a new Dataframe out of that map, and then doing a regular join on the dataframes instead.